# How to set same Variables with different Values

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, scoping

I have a pipe with different insulation sections and a fluid flowing through. I need to calculate the fluid Temperature at the end of every section, to estimate the temperature for the next section. I build my Model with Modules, the equations stay quite the same, but the characteristics (variables) for my insulation varies.
For example the Thermal Diffusivity `α=λ/(ρ *cp)`, changes per section. So i dont want to rewrite a Module for every single section. I just want a single Module to call up a Table for the specific section (for simplicitiy and preventing errors). My issue is that the variables i set, are global and hence i have to build many modules and rename my variables. Is there a possibiliy to set same variables, but different value?
Is it also possible to set a single Matrix with rows i call up, which represent each section?

For example:

```
m=Matrix[Section1{λ=1,cp=2,ρ=3},Section2{λ=4,cp=5,ρ=6},Section3{λ=7,cp=8,ρ=9}]

S1[i1_, m_] := Module[{ α=λ/(ρ *cp)}]

S2[i2_, m_] := Module[{ α=λ/(ρ *cp)}]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Certainly something can done. But without a concrete minimal(!) example, nobody will be able to  help you. Also, the occurence of `MatrixForm` rang some alarm bells with me. This tells me that you got something fundamentally wrong about its purpose: It is for displaying only. It is _not_ meant as a datatype.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about such calculations. Here is one where the parameter sets are encapsulated with [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), the Wolfram Language's equivalent of what are called hash-tables or dictionaries in other programming languages.

```
sectionParams =
  {Association[{λ -> 1, cp -> 2, ρ -> 3}],
   Association[{λ -> 4, cp -> 5, ρ -> 6}],
   Association[{λ -> 7, cp -> 8, ρ -> 9}]};
s[sp_] := sp[λ]/sp[ρ] /sp[cp]
```

Then the calculation is reduced to

```
s /@ sectionParams
```

> `{1/6, 2/15, 7/72}`